# Converting between chrono::duration types where the LCM of both denominators is large

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I ran into a problem a while back where I had to convert between two different duration types that looked like this:

```
using MyType_T = duration<long long, ratio<1, 4294967296LL>>;
using OtherType_T = duration<long long, ratio<1, 10000000>>;
```

When I use ::boost::chrono::duration_cast<> (or std::chrono::duration_cast<>, for that matter), to go from MyType_T to OtherType_T, or vice-versa, I find that these kinds of conversions can produce wrong results when the source value exceeds a certain limit.

The reason that there is a problem with just calling duration_cast(tm) is that the LCM of both denominators is represented fully in 56-bits. The conversion is done in this case, by dividing the value in tm by the LCM of the denominators, and passing this, as the common factor type, into a construction of the OtherType_T duration. This performs the multiplication to get to the right value.

As you can see, with sufficiently large values (64 or greater, in this case), this would mean that the division could shift out everything to zero, and you get nothing.

Is there any way to do this conversion without losing all precision, aside from doing the following?

1. Make a new type, Interim_T, that is just the common_type of the two, with the denominator removed. `typedef typename common_type<MyType_T, OtherType_T>::type CommonDuration;`
2. Do a duration_cast on the "From" value, tm, to the new type so as to obtain some value highbits. `auto highbits = duration_cast<duration<CommonDuration::rep, ratio<CommonDuration::num>>>(tm);`
3. Subtract highbits from the original value tm, to obtain the value lowbits. `auto lowbits = tm - highbits;`
4. To highbits, add the result of duration_cast(lowbits). This is the result. `auto result = highbits + duration_cast<OtherType_T>(lowbits);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a floating point type as the interim type:

```
using MyType_T = duration<long long, ratio<1, 4294967296LL>>;
using OtherType_T = duration<long long, ratio<1, 10000000>>;
using OtherType_F = duration<long double, OtherType_T::period>;

MyType_T x{0x7FFFFFFFFFFF};
auto y = duration_cast<OtherType_T>(OtherType_F{x});
```

The syntax is easier on the eyes, and the logic is less complicated.  Note that you'll still overflow if the result can't fit in `OtherType_T`.